# Как присвоить объекту класса значение некой функции?

Tags: классы

Допустим, есть заранее заданная функция sum, значение которой должно быть присвоено объекту класса math, как я могу передать те самые аргументы х и у для дальнейшего присовоения перемнной summ?

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

class math():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    summ = sum(x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    math.summ(5, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

а разве не через конструктор все делается?

```
def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

class math():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.summ = sum(x, y)

obj = math(5, 5)
```